# mat-tab-group tabs not rendering after switching parent tabs

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, mat-tab

I have an example where I need to use nested tabs and tables.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bgl1f2

When I switch parent tabs (View M2) and then try to switch child tabs (M3), the tabs do not render. Rendering occurs only after switching child tabs (M3) multiple times.

**Steps to Reproduce in the above Stackblitz:**

1. Open any M1 Expansion panel. This displays parent tabs (View M2) and child tabs (M3)
2. Switch to child tab (**M3 32 B**)
3. Switch to parent tab (**View M2 - 2**)
4. Switch back to previous parent tab (**View M2 - 1**)
5. Switch to child tab (**M3 33 C**)

**Expected Result**
A table should be displayed in child tab (**M3 33 C**)

**Actual Result**
Nothing is rendered in child tab (**M3 33 C**)

When you switch to a different child tab and then back to child tab (**M3 33 C**), table is displayed.

Can anyone point out what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I know, i know a bit late.
But i stumbled over this post in quest for a solution.

And i found one after all!

So here to share, and give back to the community

`<ng-template matTabContent>` did the trick for me

```
<mat-tab>
    <ng-template matTabContent>
        <div class="example-tab-content">
        ...
        </div>
    </ng-template>
</mat-tab>
```